# php mongodb updateMany ordered false not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this query, but still get `E11000 duplicate key error collection` error

```
$collection->insertMany($allData,['ordered' => false]);
```

MongoDB: 4.4, php driver version: 1.12.0

**-----------------------------Update------------------------------**

According to dododo's answer (and comments), all documents will be inserted successfully, but you will get the duplicate error at the end.

In other words, this code will insert all documents without killing the app:

```
try{
    $collection->insertMany($allData,['ordered' => false]);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Some documents are duplilcate but everthing ok.."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior that mentioned in the doc [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#unordered-inserts). Also, it's not php related, same you can see in the shell:

```
db.coll.insertMany([{ _id: 1}, {_id : 1}, {_id: 2}], {ordered: false})
```

which fails with:

```
uncaught exception: BulkWriteError({
        "writeErrors" : [
                {
                        "index" : 1,
                        "code" : 11000,
                        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.coll2 index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 1.0 }",
                        "op" : {
                                "_id" : 1
                        }
                }
        ],
        "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
        "nInserted" : 2,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

result:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.coll.find()
{ "_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2 }
```

pay attention that there are 2 inserted documents, first attempt of `{ _id: 1 }` and `{ _id : 2 }`.

Comment: Hi dododo, thanks for your time, At all how can I ignore duplicate errors without breaking the loop and continue inserting?

Comment: they are ignored, aren't they? They're in the collection after inserting, the only problem that you should handle resulted exception in one or another way, for example you can set `{ w : 0 }` write concern like: `db.coll.insertMany([{ _id: 1}, {_id : 1}, {_id: 2}], {ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: 0}})`. But be careful with this option since effectively you will say to the driver, I don't care (almost) how this command will be handled, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/#w-option

Comment: NOTE: I was probably wrong (edited answer) and first duplicated record will be always inserted

Comment: You mean it throws an error after inserting all documents?

Comment: yes, you can see it in the above example when the 3rd document was inserted even though there was error for the first ones

Comment: Wow, your right! All documents inserted successfully, I can handle it with `try-catch`, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear.

Between the array $allData and the table contents you have duplicate keys.

**CASUS: Empty Table**

So let's say your database table is:

> `_id | created_at | updated_at | value`

where `_id` is your primary key in the database.

And your $allData is

```php
$allData = [
   ['_id' => 1, 'value' => 'foo']
   ['_id' => 2, 'value' => 'bar']
   ['_id' => 3, 'value' => 'baz']
   ['_id' => 1, 'value' => 'bal']
];
```

As you can see, the primary key insert data has duplicate values, the value 1 appears twice.

This gives then an error.

The same can occur if a database column is marked with an `UNIQUE INDEX` forcing values to be unique.

Dump the data that's present in $allData, study the contents, and remove the duplicates.

**Casus: Filled table**

> `_id | created_at | updated_at | value`
> `1  | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | foo`  
> `2  | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | bar`  
> `3  | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 | baz`

And your $allData is

```php
$allData = [
   ['_id' => 1, 'value' => 'foo']
   ['_id' => 2, 'value' => 'bar']
   ['_id' => 3, 'value' => 'baz']
];
```

What happens is, it tries to insert a row into the table with primary key 1. The database engine checks for existing primary keys with that value. It finds one present, as there is already a row with primary key one. Then it throws an error, wich gets caught by php, which then throws it's own exception which ends up with you. Duplicate key found.

In that case use upsert your query with the [setOnInsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) modifier for upsert. Something like:

```php
$collection->insertMany($allData,[
       'ordered' => false, 
       'upsert' => true, 
       '$setOnInsert' => ['_id', 'value']
    ]);
```

Comment: Hi Tschallacka, Thank you for your time, According to MongoDB documentation when `'ordered'` is set `true` it should ignore the duplicate error, then why throws an error?

Comment: It's probably because you provide an `_id` field. You're not allowing mongodb to generate an id. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#_id-field